# Adding transparency to the VC on IB action - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, ibaction

I have a case where I need to open a new UIViewController on IBAction. This new UIViewController is supposed to be transparent. When I do a normal modal transition it hides the old UIViewController. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: VC????????????????? Venture Capitalist? Very Confusing?

Comment: i suppose he means View controller

Comment: why cant you just present the new VC using modal transition? i dont get the question.

Comment: the new VC is supposed to have transparent background. So the old VC can be seen

Comment: then you dont want a new vc you simply want a UIView initially hidden and set to visible when your action takes place

Comment: Luis yes that sounds more reasonable. Any samples or instructions on that u know of?

Comment: Is it possible to add buttons to the UIView using the storyboard interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purposes you will want to tell your modal View Controllers view property to change alpha. (best done in the view controllers `viewDidLoad`)

It's as simple as:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
[self.view setAlpha:0.5];
}
```

Now, the other approach would be to just use a new `UIView` added as a subview of your main view controller. The following will show your how to animate it in.

```
UIView *myNewView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
[myNewView setAlpha:0.0];
[self.view addSubview:myNewView];

[UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
    [myNewView setAlpha:0.5];
}];
```

**EDIT:** To change the alpha of the background view and preserve the alpha of its subviews, try setting it up like this.

```
[myNewView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2]];

[myNewViewsSubView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0]];
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Will setAlpha affect any items on the subview? Like in I have a button. It seems appear dull because of the setalpha function. Any suggestions?